# nil point deference in golang using govmomi library

Tags: go, govmomi

I'm trying to use the govmomi library (https://github.com/vmware/govmomi) to make some automated changes to a VM but I can't seem to get around the nil pointer exceptions on line 134 and 136 for the last few hours. I got it to work at one point but then I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong now as I've tried so many combos but nothing seems to work now...

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/soap"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "fmt"

    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/govc/flags"

    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/types"
    "log"
)


type change struct {
    *flags.VirtualMachineFlag
}

const (
    envURL      = "GOVC_URL"
    envUserName = "GOVC_USERNAME"
    envPassword = "GOVC_PASSWORD"
    envInsecure = "GOVC_INSECURE"
)

// getEnvString returns string from environment variable.
func getEnvString(v string, def string) string {
    r := os.Getenv(v)
    if r == "" {
        return def
    }

    return r
}

// getEnvBool returns boolean from environment variable.
func getEnvBool(v string, def bool) bool {
    r := os.Getenv(v)
    if r == "" {
        return def
    }

    switch strings.ToLower(r[0:1]) {
    case "t", "y", "1":
        return true
    }

    return false
}

var urlDescription = fmt.Sprintf("ESX or vCenter URL [%s]", envURL)
var urlFlag = flag.String("url", getEnvString(envURL, "https://username:password@host"+vim25.Path), urlDescription)

var insecureDescription = fmt.Sprintf("Don't verify the server's certificate chain [%s]", envInsecure)
var insecureFlag = flag.Bool("insecure", getEnvBool(envInsecure, false), insecureDescription)

func processOverride(u *url.URL) {
    envUsername := os.Getenv(envUserName)
    envPassword := os.Getenv(envPassword)

    // Override username if provided
    if envUsername != "" {
        var password string
        var ok bool

        if u.User != nil {
            password, ok = u.User.Password()
        }

        if ok {
            u.User = url.UserPassword(envUsername, password)
        } else {
            u.User = url.User(envUsername)
        }
    }

    // Override password if provided
    if envPassword != "" {
        var username string

        if u.User != nil {
            username = u.User.Username()
        }

        u.User = url.UserPassword(username, envPassword)
    }
}

func NewClient(ctx context.Context) (*govmomi.Client, error) {
    flag.Parse()

    // Parse URL from string
    u, err := soap.ParseURL(*urlFlag)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Override username and/or password as required
    processOverride(u)

    // Connect and log in to ESX or vCenter
    return govmomi.NewClient(ctx, u, *insecureFlag)
}

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    // Connect and login to ESX or vCenter
    c, err := NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer c.Logout(ctx)

    var spec *types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec

    var cmd *change

    var flip bool

    flip = false

    spec.VPMCEnabled = &flip

    vm, err := cmd.VirtualMachine()

    task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, *spec)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(task.Wait(ctx))
}
```

the 2 lines that are throwing errors are:

`spec.VPMCEnabled = &flip`

and

`vm, err := cmd.VirtualMachine()`

both seem to throw the same `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`. If I comment out the first one throwing the error, the second one throws it then.

I think both are unrelated but I can't quite figure how how to do the dereferencing correctly.

----UPDATE EDIT 1--------------

I made some changes to this with the below response but still can't get around the error on at `task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, *spec)`...

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/object"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25"
    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/soap"
    "net/url"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "fmt"

    "github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/types"
    "log"
)


const (
    envURL      = "GOVC_URL"
    envUserName = "GOVC_USERNAME"
    envPassword = "GOVC_PASSWORD"
    envInsecure = "GOVC_INSECURE"
)

// getEnvString returns string from environment variable.
func getEnvString(v string, def string) string {
    r := os.Getenv(v)
    if r == "" {
        return def
    }

    return r
}

// getEnvBool returns boolean from environment variable.
func getEnvBool(v string, def bool) bool {
    r := os.Getenv(v)
    if r == "" {
        return def
    }

    switch strings.ToLower(r[0:1]) {
    case "t", "y", "1":
        return true
    }

    return false
}

var urlDescription = fmt.Sprintf("ESX or vCenter URL [%s]", envURL)
var urlFlag = flag.String("url", getEnvString(envURL, "https://username:password@host"+vim25.Path), urlDescription)

var insecureDescription = fmt.Sprintf("Don't verify the server's certificate chain [%s]", envInsecure)
var insecureFlag = flag.Bool("insecure", getEnvBool(envInsecure, false), insecureDescription)

func processOverride(u *url.URL) {
    envUsername := os.Getenv(envUserName)
    envPassword := os.Getenv(envPassword)

    // Override username if provided
    if envUsername != "" {
        var password string
        var ok bool

        if u.User != nil {
            password, ok = u.User.Password()
        }

        if ok {
            u.User = url.UserPassword(envUsername, password)
        } else {
            u.User = url.User(envUsername)
        }
    }

    // Override password if provided
    if envPassword != "" {
        var username string

        if u.User != nil {
            username = u.User.Username()
        }

        u.User = url.UserPassword(username, envPassword)
    }
}

func NewClient(ctx context.Context) (*govmomi.Client, error) {
    flag.Parse()

    // Parse URL from string
    u, err := soap.ParseURL(*urlFlag)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Override username and/or password as required
    processOverride(u)

    // Connect and log in to ESX or vCenter
    return govmomi.NewClient(ctx, u, *insecureFlag)
}

func main() {

    ctx := context.Background()

    // Connect and login to ESX or vCenter
    c, err := NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer c.Logout(ctx)

    var spec *types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec
    spec = new(types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec)


    var flip bool

    flip = false

    spec.VPMCEnabled = &flip

    var vm *object.VirtualMachine
    vm = new(object.VirtualMachine)


    task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, *spec)
    if err != nil {
        println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(task.Wait(ctx))

}
```

the full error I'm getting is this:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x280 pc=0x14e18f6]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25.(*Client).RoundTrip(0x0, 0x1886f00, 0xc000016088, 0x1884140, 0xc000298720, 0x1884140, 0xc000298740, 0x300, 0x16e8ac0)
        /Users/ronakpatel/go/src/github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/client.go:89 +0x26
github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/methods.ReconfigVM_Task(0x1886f00, 0xc000016088, 0x1884060, 0x0, 0xc0002d0000, 0xc000288000, 0xc000080400, 0x0)
        /Users/ronakpatel/go/src/github.com/vmware/govmomi/vim25/methods/methods.go:10879 +0xb8
github.com/vmware/govmomi/object.VirtualMachine.Reconfigure(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1886f00, 0xc000016088, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/ronakpatel/go/src/github.com/vmware/govmomi/object/virtual_machine.go:207 +0x19b
main.main()
        /Users/ronakpatel/go/src/awesomeProject1/main.go:143 +0x1ec
exit status 2
```

----UPDATE EDIT 2----------

I changed somethings around and used the answer provided below but now I'm getting the error again but at this part: `task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, spec1)`

Error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x153d05a]

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
        /Users/ronakpatel/go/src/awesomeProject1/main.go:134 +0x19a
exit status 2
```

Code:

```
spec1 := types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec{
    VPMCEnabled: &[]bool{false}[0],
}

var vm *object.VirtualMachine

var vmf *flags.VirtualMachineFlag

vmf, ctx = flags.NewVirtualMachineFlag(ctx)

vm, _ = vmf.VirtualMachine()

task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, spec1)
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}

fmt.Println(task.Wait(ctx))
```

Comment: `vm, err := cmd.VirtualMachine()` Check the error before you use `vm`.

Comment: it doesn't get that far though cause of point exception....

Comment: Well then where does it get to? Saying "134 and 136" when the line i highlighted is on 133 in the given example code (+1 line for the missing package statement) doesn't help. Just provide accurate info if you want accurate help.

Comment: You should also provide the relevant part of the error that you're getting

Comment: ah didn't see that....just made an edit to it to correct it on the lines....it stops at 134 and when i comment that out...it stops at 136....both with these errors: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`

Comment: still that doesn't compute, there's nothing on line 134 and line 136 cannot cause that kind of error. See line numbers here (https://play.golang.org/p/HV8yJewz8mM)

Comment: That is not the relevant part of the error, show the stack that lists the files, lines, and functions that cause the error. And please don't put that into a comment but update the question instead.

Comment: It is highly probable that the package you're using provides proper constructors for the types you keep initializing with `new`. Look at that package's documentation and especially at the documentation for the types you need and see if there aren't any `NewXxx` functions to support those types. Like for example `NewVirtualMachine`, `NewVirtualMachineConfigSpec` etc, if there are then use them instead of `new`. Also a lot of packages provide examples in the docs on how to properly initialize the types that those packages declare.

Comment: ... https://godoc.org/github.com/vmware/govmomi/object#NewVirtualMachine

Answer (score 3):

```
    var spec *types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec // error: spec is nil pointer
    spec = new(types.VirtualMachineConfigSpec) // fix: spec is not nil

    var cmd *change

    var flip bool

    flip = false

    // used here
    spec.VPMCEnabled = &flip

    vm, err := cmd.VirtualMachine()
```

Comment: thanks! got my closer but this part is still throwing the same error: `vm, err := cmd.VirtualMachine()`

Comment: @lightweight when you declare a pointer variable, without initializing it, it will be nil, calling a method on such a variable will almost always get you that error. Whatever you use in your code, just make sure it's initialized.

Comment: @lightweight ok, the `*flags.VirtualMachineFlag` in `*change` is still nil pointer

Comment: @lightweight https://godoc.org/github.com/vmware/govmomi/govc/flags#NewVirtualMachineFlag  you can declare `*flags.VirtualMachineFlag` follow the doc

Comment: ah thanks! so I made some changes you stated and also cleaned up some stuff (I think), but now I'm getting that same error at this now `task, err := vm.Reconfigure(ctx, spec1)` :-( ....also, thanks for being patience....

Comment: @lightweight guess check the error in `vm, _ = vmf.VirtualMachine()` will be helpful